# Twitter bootstrap best practice advice needed

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, frontend, grid-layout

I have the following scenario

I have a classical form layout as shown below, with a label and text box in 2 lines. So the page needs to be converted to use the new Bootstrap layout.

[image]

Method 1 :-  1 row with 2 "col-md-12" grids.

Method 2 :-  2 rows with one "col-md-12" in each row.

Which is the best practice for future expansion? I think the 1st method is correct. Because if he ever needs to have the inputbox next to the label, he can simply adjust the grid sizes to fit into one row. eg:- col-md-4  and  col-md-8

Answer (score 0):

Method 1 is the best practice .

If you are using horizontal form then bootstrap has provided its own class **.form-horizontal**  see the code snippet below :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>My Form</h2>
  <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Email:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Password:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">          
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password">
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">        
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```